# C++: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'size_t'?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use snprintf inside a c++ module, using this code:

```
snprintf(err, "%s%s", "Fatal Error! ", err);
```

but I'm getting the error of "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'size_t'",
 when compiling my program, so how to solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for snprintf, specifically the arguments? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);

Comment: Even if you add the size of the buffer, you can not use `err` as both a parameter to pass to `...` for formatting and as the output buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`snprintf` has the following prototype:

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)
```

Argument two should be the maximum size of your char buffer (i.e. `err`), which here has your format string. It is used as a "safer" `sprintf`, since the function will not write more than `size` bytes to the buffer, hence goes some way to prevent overflows. In this case, I assume you just want to use standard `sprintf`, which has the following prototype:

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Comment: yeah, you right, I was confusing between snprintf and sprintf, I must use sprintf instead, thanks, that really helps!

Comment: No worries! Please mark as an answer if it helped. I'd take on board what Daniel Frey says in the post comments though, you can't write into `err` and read from it at the same time. Think about it logically, it'll try and write into it to write the "Fatal Error" string, then read from it to write the rest without ever dropping the `NULL` terminator. I don't actually know what would happen, but my intuition would be it'd just write "Fatal Error!" an infinite number of times until it segfaults.

Comment: I understand, all right.

Answer (score 1):

In C this function is declared the following way

```
int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

As you see the second parameter has type `size_t` but in the call of the function you used the second parameter has type `const char *`

```
snprintf(err, "%s%s", "Fatal Error! ", err);
```

So you simply use the function incorrectly.

The second parameter specifies how many characters you are going to read in variavle s. Usually n is set to the size of the character array pointed by s.

Comment: +1 for the C prototype. That the output is `char* restrict` means that it's undefined behavior to use `err` as both an input and as one of the variable length arguments.

Comment: @David Hammen You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the manual page?

You are missing the size of the buffer `err` as per the manual http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf

**EDIT**

Anyway better ways to do this in C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/